# An inequality with Gamma Function

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

Consider the following function for any $a, b > 0$

$$
\
g\left( a,b\right) = \frac{%
3\Gamma \left( 3b+1\right) }{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{a}+3b+1\right) }-\frac{%
5\Gamma \left( 2b+1\right) }{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{a}+2b+1\right) }+\frac{%
2\Gamma \left( b+1\right) }{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{a}+b+1\right) }
\
$$

I am interested in the region $(a,b)$ such that $g\left( a,b\right)\geqslant0$.

---

I know that this can be negative (for example for $a = 1$, $b < \frac{1}{3}$, this is negative). My conjecture is that for almost all $a, b$ couple the sign is positive. My main interest in the problem is when $a, b \geqslant 1$ and I conjecture that the inequality holds in this region. However, I do not have a general proof. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any motivation for considering this function? Perhaps that would shed some light on the problem.

Comment: [Here's a plot](http://i.imgur.com/9K3D5N4.png) showing the region where $g$ is positive in the $(a,b)$-plane.  It looks like it should be positive for all $a>0$ and $b\geq 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Yes, thanks, that is what I was also expecting. Any idea how to prove his?

Comment: I just want to point out that if you replace the constant $2$ appearing in the numerator and denominator of the middle term with $\frac{11}{5}$, the inequality follows from a very straightforward application of Jensen's inequality. Since you haven't given any motivation or source for this inequality, I am tempted to think you copied it down wrong or something.

Comment: @pre-kidney: Thank you for this observation, question is as stated, it is not copied from somewhere as you are tempted to think. I do not have a motivation for this question because this function came from a completely irrelevant "non-math" problem. While I was working on that problem, this function came up and I will be able to make some conclusions regarding that problem depending on the sign of this function.